# Delete table name

Tags: ios, numbers

That must be probably obvious, but I can't seem to figure out how to *delete* the table name. Only the *hide* option is available.

- create table
- default name "Table 1" appears
- don't want it - and don't want to allocate memory (...) for it
- tried among others: select able, tap paintbrush, options... to delete it, to no avail.

Cannot delete the name (only Hide is available). Is there a way to do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Every table must have a name and it can't be deleted. This isn't very apparent with simple spreadsheets but formulas that reference other tables use the table name to find the cell. The table name can't be removed as its required for these cross-table formulas.

I recommend naming all your tables, even if you then hide the table name, so that you don't end up with a bunch of formulas referencing table 7 from table 4 and table 6 from table 2.

Comment: For the record, setting the name to *nil* (nothing) makes the row disappear (just discovered that).

Comment: @ring0 Yes, but this is the same as hiding it. The table retains a name for the aforementioned purpose.